# App crashes within for loop in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am just getting array count and using for loop but got crashed at `let arr = arrayAdaptor[i]` this line after completing my array count don't know why it's crashing can anyone help me how to resolve this

```
var arrayAdaptor  = [Struct_Row_Rating]()

for i in 0...arrayAdaptor.count {
            let arr = arrayAdaptor[i]
            let number = arr.row
            let row = number + 1
            dict.updateValue("\(arr.rating)", forKey: "\(row)")
            print(dict)
        }
struct Struct_Row_Rating {
    var row: Int
    var rating: Double

    init(row: Int , rating: Double) {
        self.row = row
        self.rating = rating

    }}
```

Comment: Obviously array count gives 1 more index.

Comment: How it will get more index I had printed the saved array it is having what I selected got saved @Desdenova

Comment: for i in 0...arrayAdaptor.count-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why you are using `0...arrayAdaptor.count` range style avoid it and Simply Use enumerated() of an Array:**

```
for (_,value) in arrayAdaptor.enumerated() {
      let number = value.row
      let row = number + 1
      dict.updateValue("\(arr.rating)", forKey: "\(row)")
      print(dict)
 }
```

**If you don't want any index to try with this:**

```
for value in arrayAdaptor { 
      let number = value.row
      let row = number + 1
      dict.updateValue("\(arr.rating)", forKey: "\(row)")
      print(dict)
}
```

[See this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)

Comment: Using `enumerated` and not considering the *enumerated* index is nonsensical.

Answer (score 8):

The operator `...` exceeds the range of the array. You have to write

```
for i in 0..<arrayAdaptor.count
```

or

```
for i in 0...arrayAdaptor.count - 1
```

---

Basically **don't use these index based `for` loops in Swift at all**.

Use `Fast Enumeration`:

```
for arr in arrayAdaptor {
```

and if you really need the index

```
for (index, arr) in arrayAdaptor.enumerated() {
```

Comment: `index-based` and `C-style` is not the same. `C-style index-based` `for` loops are extinct from the language since Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options not mentioned in the answers is `forEach` approach.

```
arrayAdaptor.forEach { item in
   print(item)
}
```

or

```
arrayAdaptor.forEach { 
   print($0) // without named parameter
}
```

// Your case:

```
arrayAdaptor.forEach { item in
    let arr = item
    let number = item.row
    let row = number + 1
    dict.updateValue("\(arr.rating)", forKey: "\(row)")
    print(dict)
}
```

This is pretty much the same as the handy `for..in` mentioned in **vadian**'s answer:

```
for arr in arrayAdaptor { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

From **Swift 4** you can use [One sided ranges](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md).

`i...` is favored over `i..<` because the latter is ugly. We have to pick one, two would be redundant and likely to cause confusion over which is the "right" one. Either would be reasonable on pedantic correctness grounds – `(i as Int)...` includes Int.max consistent with `...,` whereas `a[i...]` is interpreted as `a[i..<a.endIndex]` consistent with `i..<.`

**Example:**

```
var names = ["Jack", "New", "peter"]
        let first = names[0...]
        let second = names[..<names.count]
        print(first)//prints ["Jack", "New", "peter"]
        print(second)//prints ["Jack", "New", "peter"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate loop by 'map' function:

```
    let _ = arrayAdaptor.map({ adaptor in

            let number = adaptor.row
            let row = number + 1

            dict.updateValue("\(adaptor.rating)", forKey: "\(row)")
            print(dict)
     })
```